# Multiple dimensional array[key] notation fails on jQuery ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I tried to use array[key] notation to dynamically add then send multiple dimensional array data :

```
var record=[];
record['main']={};
record['sub']={};
record['main']['mainId']=$("#goto").val();
record['main']['year']=$('#year').val(); 
record['main']['month']=$('#month').val();
record['main']['date']=$('#date').val(); 
record['main']['bank_account']=$('#bank_account').val();
record['main']['voucher_type']=$('#voucher_type').val(); 
record['main']['voucher_no']=$('#voucher_no').val();
record['main']['main_subject']=$('#main_subject').val(); 
record['main']['main_summary']=$('#main_summary').val();

 $('[id^=sub_money]').each( function (index, Element) {
    record['sub'][index]=[];
    record['sub'][index]['sub_subject']=$('#sub_subject'+(index+1));
    record['sub'][index]['sub_summary']=$('#sub_summary'+(index+1));
    record['sub'][index]['sub_money']=$('#sub_money'+(index+1));
    record['sub'][index]['sub_chequeId']=$('#sub_chequeId'+(index+1));
    record['sub'][index]['sub_pyaee']=$('#sub_payee'+(index+1));
    record['sub'][index]['sub_chequeDate']=$('#sub_chequeDate'+(index+1));
});
```

But `.ajax()` returns nothing :

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType:'jason',
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'update_voucher.php',
    data:{'record': record},
    success: function(data) {   
        $("#message").html("Something has changed<br>"+data);
    }
});
```

PHP server code just echoes (an empty array ):

```
print_r($_GET);
```

JSON-encoded array works for static things like this:

```
var record = {
    foo:  123,
    bar:  456,
    rows: [
    {
        column1 : 'hello',
        column2 : 'hola',
        column3 : 'bonjour',
    },
    {
        column1 : 'goodbye',
        column2 : 'hasta luego',
        column3 : 'au revoir',
    },
    ],
    test1:{
       test2: {
          test3:  'baz'
       }
    }
};
```

But not for dynamic ones like this:

```
 var record=[]; record['sub']={};
 record['sub'][index]=[];
 record['sub'][index]['sub_subject']='abc';
```

Tested on jQuery 1.51, Firefox 7.01 , Ubuntu Linux 10.04 LTS

Comment: Do you mean JSON? I don't know what jason is and I don't think jQuery does either. But in any case I cannot make sense out of the code snippets you posted.

Comment: `dataType:'jason',` should be `JSON`. I wanted to edit the title to change jason into JSON, but as it seems to be one of the problems in the code, I left it as it is ;)

Answer (score 1):

An object in JavaScript allows you to store arbitrary properties and values.

An array is a particular kind of object that is supposed to contain numerical indexed, sequential data and gets some extra properties such as `length` and `join`.

You are storing data in arbitrary named properties, but you are doing so on an array. When you pass the array to jQuery it sees that it is an array and assumes you are using numerical indexed, sequential data … so it ignores all the extra properties you have added.

Use an object `{}` not an array `[]`.

Comment: The problem is the [param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) method (called by *jQuery.ajax*) which assumes that if it's passed an array, it's an array of objects from a serialised form. It will only correctly serialise an array of objects that have only *name* and *value* properties, e.g. `[{name:'fred',value:'foo'},{name:'bar',value:'fum']`. It will not properly serialise any other type of array.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you're muddling arrays with objects. There's a much tidier way to write your code that makes it much more obvious what is going on:

```
var record = {
    main: {
        mainId:       $("#goto").val(),
        year:         $('#year').val(), 
        month:        $('#month').val(),
        date:         $('#date').val(),
        bank_account: $('#bank_account').val(),
        voucher_type: $('#voucher_type').val(),
        voucher_no:   $('#voucher_no').val(),
        main_subject: $('#main_subject').val(),
        main_summary: $('#main_summary').val(),
    },
    sub: []
}

$('[id^=sub_money]').each(function(i) {
    record.sub[i] = {
        sub_subject:    $('#sub_subject'    + (i+1)).val(),
        sub_summary:    $('#sub_summary'    + (i+1)).val(),
        sub_money:      $('#sub_money'      + (i+1)).val(),
        sub_chequeId:   $('#sub_chequeId'   + (i+1)).val(),
        sub_payee:      $('#sub_payee'      + (i+1)).val(),
        sub_chequeDate: $('#sub_chequeDate' + (i+1)).val()
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, with just a little modification, then it worked! change main= to main: sub= to sub: and add .val() to the and of each  $('#..'+(i+1))

Comment: If I've solved your problem, don't forget to click the tick next to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) expects the data to be an Object or a String, not an array. It uses the [param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) method to stringify the data it has been passed.

If you pass it an array, it assumes it is an array of objects representing name/value pairs from a serialised form and will turn:

```
var a = [
         {name:'fred', value:'foo'}, 
         {name:'bar',  value:'fum'}
        ];
```

into the string:

```
'fred=foo&bar=fum'
```

Pass it an array with any other structure and you'll get rubbish (or nothing).

You may be able to avoid this behaviour by setting the *processData* option to *false*, or by converting the array to a string yourself so that jQuery doesn't do anything to it.